# How to retrieve data from mysql to chart.js

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, chart.js

I want to create a pie chart with chart.js, but it can't display the chart. I spent a day trying to solve this problem, but there was no good result. I hope someone can help me.

My database has different companies, I need to calculate the total sales of each company and display in the pie chart.

I think the problem would be ***$results_sum = "SELECT SUM(total_of_gp_fee) AS Total FROM gp WHERE `cshortcut`=$subjectData('cshortcut')";***, since there has many sales record for different company and I am not sure if that is correct code.

```
<?php
include_once("connection.php");
$results_sum = "SELECT cshortcut,SUM(total_of_gp_fee) AS Total FROM gp GROUP BY cshortcut";
$result_sum = mysqli_query($conn, $results_sum) or die("error to fetch data");
if ($result_sum->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
$labels = $data = '';
while($row = $result_sum->fetch_assoc()) {

    //get the company name separated by comma for chart labels
    $labels.= '"' .$row["cshortcut"]. '",';

    //get the total separated by comma for chart data
    $data.= $row["Total"].',';
}
}?>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>test</title>
<script src="chart/Chart.bundle.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <canvas id="myChart" width="300" height="100"></canvas>
</div>
```

script part

```
<script>
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'pie',
        data: {
            labels: [<?php echo trim($labels);?>],
        datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [<?php echo trim($data);?>],
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                        'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
                    ],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }]
        },
        options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
        },

        //Add the tooltips
        tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(tooltipItem) {
                        return "€ " + Number(tooltipItem.yLabel);
                    }
                }
        },
    }
        },
     );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- get the company name and SUM of total_of_gp_fee group by company.

```
include_once("connection.php");

//get the company name and total_of_gp_fee of that company.
$results_sum = "SELECT cshortcut,SUM(total_of_gp_fee) AS Total FROM gp GROUP BY cshortcut";
$result_sum = mysqli_query($conn, $results_sum) or die("error to fetch data");
if ($result_sum->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    $labels = $data = '';
    while($row = $result_sum->fetch_assoc()) {

        //get the company name separated by comma for chart labels
        $labels.= '"' .$row["cshortcut"]. '",';

        //get the total separated by comma for chart data
        $data.= $row["Total"].',';
    }
}
```

2- Update the value of labels and data in chart.

```
labels: [<?php echo trim($labels);?>],
            datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    data: [<?php echo trim($data);?>],
```

3- **Add the tooltips for bar chart.**

```
options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true
                        }
                    }]
            },

            //Add the tooltips
            tooltips: {
                    callbacks: {
                        label: function(tooltipItem) {
                            return "€" + Number(tooltipItem.yLabel);
                        }
                    }
            },
        }
```

4- **Add tooltips for pie chart.**

```
tooltips: {
                callbacks: {
                    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                        var allData = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data;
                        var tooltipData = allData[tooltipItem.index];
                        var total = 0;
                        for (var i in allData) {
                            total += allData[i];
                        }
                        var tooltipPercentage = Math.round((tooltipData / total) * 100);
                        return "€" + ': ' + tooltipData + ' (' + tooltipPercentage + '%)';
                    }
                }
            },
```

Comment: hi, thanks again, but how to display EURO Symbol in front of the number? I have try  to do like this  data: [<?php while ($p = mysqli_fetch_array($result_sum)) { echo '"'  . "€" . $p['Total'] . '",';}?>], but it doesn't work.

Comment: In the bar chart remove the € symbol from data otherwise it will not work. Add tooltips within option to make custom labels. I added in code please have a look.

Comment: I tried it's working for me. Can you please update your complete java script code. I will check.

Comment: You are using bar chart or pie chart.? Update your complete jQuery code

Comment: I updated complete javascript code, I have try bar chart which success to show € symbol with sales number now, but it could only show € symbol without sales number when turn to pie chart, is it possible to show percentage as well? thanks

Comment: Hi, update the code to  show percentage as well for pie chart. Please check

Comment: Thanks, it works. Please help again if you have time https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56539523/how-can-i-update-all-row-from-database-and-show-updated-data-without-reflesh/56539804#56539804

Comment: If it's working. Can you please vote up?  thank you.. :)

Comment: certainly, you help me a lot, I thought I have already voted you, how about now? actually I don't how to vote...

Comment: Yes, now it's okay. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: See the link for vote. https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up

Answer (score 0):

I think cshortcut holds the name of the comany, so you can do it all with one query:

```
$results_sum = "SELECT cshortcut,SUM(total_of_gp_fee) AS Total FROM gp GROUP BY cshortcut";
```

And you will get an array with to elements (cshortcut and Total) for each element in the array

Anyway, you have an error in your JS, you are using a name that doesn 't exist in your data (total_of_gp_fee) because you are using an alias (Total), you should change:

```
        labels: [<?php while ($b = mysqli_fetch_array($result_cut)) { echo '"' . $b['cshortcut'] . '",';}?>],
        datasets: [{
                label: '# of Votes',
                data: [<?php while ($p = mysqli_fetch_array($sum)) { echo '"' . $p['Total'] . '",';}?>],
```

Comment: data: [<?php while ($p = mysqli_fetch_array($sum)) { echo '"' . $p['Total'] . '",';}?>], should change to data: [<?php while ($p = mysqli_fetch_array($result_sum)) { echo '"' . $p['Total'] . '",';}?>], Thanks