# duplicate value in typeahead

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using typeahead in my page, it can display value from database, but the value will be duplicate, for example the value is hotel and it will save hotelhotel in database. anyone know the solution?

index.php

```
<script src="typeahead.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input.typeahead').typeahead({
    name: 'typeahead',
    remote:'search.php?key=%QUERY',
    limit : 20
});
});
</script>

<td><input type="text" name="typeahead" class="typeahead tt-query, cal_amount typeahead" autocomplete="on" spellcheck="false" value="<?php echo $res['supplier'];?>"><input type="hidden" value="" name="typeahead" /></td>
```

search.php

```
<?php
$key=$_GET['key'];
$array = array();
include_once("connection.php");

$query=mysqli_query($con, "select * from supplier where cname LIKE '%{$key}%'");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  $array[] = $row['cname'];

}
echo json_encode($array);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Pls do not ask multiple questions in a single post. Makes answering, answer acceptance, and searching difficult.

Comment: I adjust to one question.

Comment: There is no code that relates to the question because none of the samples inckude an insert statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used AJAX to execute PHP script by passing the Typeahead field input as the query parameter to process the SELECT to get data for the autocomplete suggestion.
for more details you can follow the below link.

https://phppot.com/jquery/bootstrap-autocomplete-with-dynamic-data-load-using-php-ajax/

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>        
<script src="typeahead.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.typeahead').typeahead({
            source: function (query, result) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "search.php",
                    data: 'query=' + query,            
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    success: function (data) {
                        result($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return item;
                        }));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>

<td><input type="text" name="typeahead" class="typeahead tt-query, cal_amount typeahead" autocomplete="on" spellcheck="false" value=""><input type="hidden" value="" name="typeahead" /></td>
```

search.php

```
<?php       
    $keyword = strval($_POST['query']);
    $search_param = "{$keyword}%";
    $conn =new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '' , 'test');

    $sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM supplier WHERE cname LIKE ?");
    $sql->bind_param("s",$search_param);            
    $sql->execute();
    $result = $sql->get_result();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $countryResult[] = $row["cname"];
        }
        echo json_encode($countryResult);
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

**Solution 2 - Without ajax.**

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "test");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$query=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from supplier");
$data = '';
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    // SELECT to get data for the autocomplete suggestion
    $data.= '"' .$row["cname"]. '",';
}

?>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>        
<script src="typeahead.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substringRegex;

    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
    matches = [];

    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

    // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
    // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
        matches.push(str);
      }
    });

    cb(matches);
  };
};

var data = [<?php echo rtrim($data, ',');?>
];

$('.typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  source: substringMatcher(data)
});

});
</script>
<input type="text" name="typeahead" class="typeahead tt-query, cal_amount typeahead" autocomplete="on" spellcheck="false" value=""><input type="hidden" value="" name="typeahead" />
```

Comment: Thanks, that one works for me,  I am trying to edit the code which can display the other data from the same ID in the other td column, for example the value is a hotel's name and the other column to display the price of room for this hotel