# how to use onchange to update mysql automatically when change the value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am editing a code which supposed to update database when value is change, however it doesn't work, hope someone could help me fix it.

I am using DISTINCT to get the data and need to update a few data at the same time. it can display the value, but it can't save in database.

for example, I will using DISTINCT to get a few data which with the same date and I will change values among those data at the same time by using that code.

index.php

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {

        $(".cal_amount").change(function() {
            var auto_array = {};

            //Step 1- On change use The closest() method to get the all input elements value of selected element row.
            form_data = $(this).closest('tr').find('input, select');

            //Step 2- On change Use map to store input elements value with name as key in the array.
            var myArray = $.map(form_data, function(element) {
                    auto_array[element.name] = element.value;
                    //return {name: element.name, value: element.value};
            });

  form_data = $(this).closest('tr').find('input,select').serialize();
        $.ajax({
                data: {
                    action: 'update_price',
                    form_data: form_data,
                },
                url: 'updates_ok.php',
                type: 'post',
                beforeSend: function() {

                },
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data == 1){
                    alert('update sucessful')}
                }
            });
    });


    };

    </script>

<script>
    window.onload = function() {

        $(".day_record").change(function() {
            var auto_array = {};

            //Step 1- On change use The closest() method to get the all input elements value of selected element row.
            form_data = $(this).closest('tr').find('input, select');

            //Step 2- On change Use map to store input elements value with name as key in the array.
            var myArray = $.map(form_data, function(element) {
                    auto_array[element.name] = element.value;
                    //return {name: element.name, value: element.value};
            });


  form_data = $(this).closest('tr').find('input,select').serialize();
        $.ajax({
                data: {
                    action: 'update_data',
                    form_data: form_data,
                },
                url: 'updates_ok.php',
                type: 'post',
                beforeSend: function() {

                },
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data == 1){
                    alert('update sucessful');}
                }
            });
    });


    };

    </script>
```

update.php

```
<?php

if($_POST['action'] == 'update_price'){
//parse the serialize data
parse_str($_POST['form_data'], $my_form_data);

/*echo "<pre>";
print_r($my_form_data);*/

$id = $my_form_data['id']; 
$gp_name = $my_form_data['gp_name']; 
$price = $my_form_data['price'];
$cost = $my_form_data['cost']; 

$sql= $query = $finalquery = $sqlresult = '';

if($cost){
$sql.="cost='$cost',";
}

if($price){
$sql.="price='$price',";
}

$finalquery = rtrim($sql,',');
$query="UPDATE `gp_info` SET $finalquery where id=$id";

$sqlresult=mysql_query($query);
if($sqlresult){
$reback=1;
}else{
$reback=0;
}
echo $reback;
}

if($_POST['action'] == 'update_data'){
//parse the serialize data
parse_str($_POST['form_data'], $my_form_data);

/*echo "<pre>";
print_r($my_form_data);*/

$gp_name = $my_form_data['gp_name']; 
$date = $my_form_data['date']; 
$day = $my_form_data['day']; 

$sql= $query = $finalquery = $sqlresult = '';


if($date){
$sql.="date='$date',";
}   

if($day){
$sql.="day='$day',";
}

$finalquery = rtrim($sql,',');
$query="UPDATE `gp_info` SET $finalquery where gp_name='$gp_name' AND             date='$date' AND day='$day'";
$sqlresult=mysql_query($query);
if($sqlresult){
$reback=1;
}else{
$reback=0;
}
echo $reback;
}
?>
```

Comment: 1. You would greatly benefit from better formatting of your code. 2. Your code is highly vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) and should not be used!!!

Comment: you are closing the foreach loop before the tr tag. closed after tr. <?php foreach($queryRecords_t as $res) :?><tr>----</tr><?php endforeach;?>

Comment: Thanks for you guys advise, @Shivendra Singh thanks, I have put it outside of <tr>, but the problem is about save in database, I guess the problem from the script side?

Comment: Yes, check the update query.

Comment: @Shivendra Singh  I realize that the code is working fine if I put it in different page, because I need to run the same script in one page, the problem might be the same function name or something has been duplicated, if so, could you help me conbine two script together or give different name for both script? I have update the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code. I mention the details in code with comments.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            $(".update_row_data").change(function() {
             //On change of update_row_data get the action name from current row
              action =    $(this).closest('tr').data('action');
              form_data = $(this).closest('tr').find('input,select').serialize();
                    $.ajax({
                            data: {

                               //Use that action name in ajax request.
                                action: action,
                                form_data: form_data,
                            },
                            url: 'updates_ok.php',
                            type: 'post',
                            beforeSend: function() {

                            },
                            success: function(data) {
                                if(data == 1){
                                alert('update sucessful')}
                            }
                        });
                });

        };
    </script>

    <table border="1" align="center" style="table-layout:fixed">
        <tbody id="_editable_table">
        <!-- Add action name in row item with data attr-->
            <tr data-action="update_price">

                <!-- Add common class 'update_row_data' to all required field. -->
                <input name="gp_name" style="border-style:none" type="hidden" class="update_row_data gp_name" value="">
                <th>Date</th><td width="350px"><input name="date" size="10" style="border-style:none" type="text" class="update_row_data date" value=""></td>
                <th>Country</th><td><input name="country" size="6" style="border-style:none"     type="text" class="update_row_data country" value="">    </td>
                <th>City</th><td><input name="city" size="8" style="border-style:none" type="text" class="update_row_data city" value=""></td>        
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>




    <table border="1" align="center" style="table-layout:fixed">
        <tbody id="_editable_table">
            <!-- Add action name in row item with data attr-->
            <tr data-action="update_data">

            <!-- Add common class 'update_row_data' to all required field. -->

            <input name="gp_name" style="border-style:none" type="hidden" class="update_row_data gp_name" value="">
            <th>Date</th><td width="350px"><input name="date" size="10" style="border-style:none" type="text" class="update_row_data date" value=""></td>
            <th>Country</th><td><input name="country" size="6" style="border-style:none"     type="text" class="update_row_data country" value="">    </td>
            <th>City</th><td><input name="city" size="8" style="border-style:none" type="text" class="update_row_data city" value=""></td>  
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Hi Shivendra again, can you help me with this?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58727528/how-to-retrieve-data-from-mysql-through-ajax-or-jquery-to-show-chinese-font-corr?noredirect=1#comment103749385_58727528

Comment: hi Shivendra, I have the other question about this code. what if I need use textarea instead of input, how do I rewrite the code? I have try to add textarea in form_data = $(this).closest('tr').find('input,select,textarea').serialize();, but I doesn't work. the other question is if I need to calculate a input column from the other table, how do I write? let say a input name=profit and id=profit